# What is the time complexity of this coin changing combination algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, coin-change

Hello I have just solved this leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change-2/

The objective is to find the number of different possible combinations of `coins` we can use to generate an `amount` assuming we have an infinite number of coins from each denomination.

I know this problem has a DP solution that runs in `O(amount*len(coins))` and I can add memoization to the solution below to achieve that.

However I am struggling to find the time complexity of the naïve approach below:

```
def change(amount, coins):
    def helper(amount, coins, id):
        if amount == 0:
            return 1
        res = 0
        for i in range(id, len(coins)):
            if coins[i] <= amount:
                res += helper(amount - coins[i], coins, i)
        return res

    res = helper(amount, coins, 0)
    return res
```

So what I am actually doing is a DFS where I try to use the first coin as much as possible before backtracking and moving to the next coin. So once I start to use the next coin I can't use the first one again --> this allows me to not count permutations in my result.

I know the time complexity of this solution is `O(exponential)` and I also know it is `O(V + E)` because it is DFS.

Can someone give the exact form of the time complexity ? What is the exponential term exactly ? Or how can I count the edges and vertices in my graph ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume a case where amount, n, is very large and the values of each coin is very small compared to n and let the size of the coin array be c. In fact, in the worst case, we can assume the value of every coin to be about 1. In the tree representing the call stack that your solution builds, each node would branch c times. Each level of the tree subtracts the value of a coin (in the worst case is about 1) from n so the depth (or height) of the tree would be n. So we're looking at a c-branch tree with height n. The number of vertices, V = c^0 + c^1 + c^2 + c^3 + ... + c^(n-1) + c^n. You can see what this series reduces to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260809/show-1-a-a2-a3-ldots-an-fracan1-1a-1-by-induction). The calculation for number of edges, E, is similar. This algorithm has O(c^n) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note here

1. Dynamic Programming is a concept or an idea. It's not an algorithm in and of itself. It's a technique used to boost the running time of some algorithms where there is a potential for subproblems to overlap and use pre computed results. There is a possibility that none of the subproblems overlap and this is the worst case complexity that people talk about.
2. So let's proceed with the assumption that no subproblems overlap and we take a top down approach and you have *c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, ... c<sub>n</sub>* as your coin denominations

I ***think*** the below would work,

Therefore a top down approach would look like this

[image]

Some paths will terminate as leaves that end in 0. (that method yielded a perfect cut up of the init amount *k* ). Some did not.

For the sake of complexity, let's assume all of them did.

So at any given level you have *n<sup>level_num</sup>* nodes. And you have to traverse every node of the tree.

The longest path would be where you kept removing the smallest denomination form the init amount *k*. i.i *k/c<sub>1</sub>*

Therefore the true time complexity in your case would be *O(1+n<sup>1</sup>+n<sup>2</sup>+....n<sup>k/c<sub>1</sub></sup>)*

Most such problems have 1 as a valid denomination of the coin (or some other small number) to simplify this expression and make the GP easier to calculate